# How do I specify include and lib paths to node.js npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install a node.js module (zmq in this case) with npm install. The C lib needed for this module is not installed in a standard location. How do I specify extra include paths and lib paths to npm? I've tried things like "CFLAGS="-I/path/to/include" npm install" with no effect.

Comment: I've been fighting the same issue, and got it working by setting `CXXFLAGS` before, along with the `-L` in `LDFLAGS` before the npm install.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832321/node-gyp-and-custom-dependency-library-header-install-path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [zeromq module](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node) can be built as follows (other modules may work the same):

- download the zip file and unpack into a temporary location e.g. `/tmp/zeromq.node-master`
- edit the `binding.gyp` file
- find the section that corresponds with your OS and add your include `-I` and library `-L` paths there.

e.g.

```
['OS=="linux"', {
  'cflags': [
    '<!(pkg-config libzmq --cflags 2>/dev/null || echo "")',
    '-I/usr/local/zeromq3/include'
  ],
  'libraries': [
    '<!(pkg-config libzmq --libs 2>/dev/null || echo "")',
    '-L/usr/local/zeromq3/lib'
  ],
}],
```

- Run npm install on the temporary directory:  `npm install /tmp/zeromq.node-master`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (does not require any file changes) is to use pkg-config's `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable, which should point to the location where the libraries are installed. If zmq has been installed at `/opt/zmq` then `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/zmq/lib/pkgconfig pkg-config libzmq --libs` should return `-L/opt/zmq/lib -lzmq` and `npm install` can be run with
`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/zmq/lib/pkgconfig npm install`

Before node app is started `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` must be set accordingly, i.e: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/zmq/lib node app.js`