# Node-gyp and custom dependency / library / header install path

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp, grpc

I have a build environment in which my libraries (and headers) are installed to a custom location. When installing a package from npm, modules that use node-gyp fail because they cannot find the libraries (or headers) I've installed. How can I make node-gyp aware of my custom install location (linux)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` before `npm install <pkg>` in the same line, it seems to work:

```
$ CXXFLAGS=-I/path/to/include LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/lib npm install <pkg>
```

Alternatively you can export the flags prior to the `npm install`

```
$ export CXXFLAGS=-I/path/to/include
$ export LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/lib
$ npm install <native-package>
```

Comment: This information is now in the [Node gRPC README](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/node#installation) as of about half an hour ago.

Comment: What a coincidence... Thanks again @murgatroid99 !